# How to initialize all fields of a big class with two different fields in standard C++

Tags: c++

I have a very big class with a bunch of members, and I want to initialize them with a given specific value.The code below is the most naive implementation, but I don't like it since it's inelegant and hard to maintain because I have to list all the members in the constructor.

```cpp
struct I_Dont_Like_This_Approach {
    int foo;
    long bar;
    unsigned baz;
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
    SomeStruct and_so_on;
    /*...*/

public:
    explicit I_Dont_Like_This_Approach(int i) : foo(i), bar(i), baz(i), a(i), b(i), c(i), d(i), and_so_on(i) /*...*/ {}
};
```

I thought of an alternative implementation using templates.

```cpp
template <int N>
struct MyBigClass {
    int foo{N};
    long bar{N};
    unsigned baz{N};
    int a{N};
    int b{N};
    int c{N};
    int d{N};
    SomeStruct and_so_on{N};
    /*...*/
};
```

but I'm not sure if the code below is safe.

```cpp
MyBigClass<1> all_one;
MyBigClass<2> all_two;
/* Is the following reinterpret_cast safe? */
all_one = reinterpret_cast<decltype(all_one) &>(all_two);
```

Does the C++ specification have any guarantees about the data layout compatibility of such templated structs? Or is there a more reasonable implementation? (in standard C++, and don't use macros)

Comment: "I have a very big class with a bunch of members" thats the problem you should solve instead of looking for workarounds. A long member initializer list is just one symptom of a class that does too much

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` is not a any-to-any cast. If its not on this list: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast then it is not defined. I would actually argue that `reinterpret_cast` is the wrong tool here, no matter if you can get it to do the right thing

Comment: its also not clear what exactly you expect `all_one = reinterpret_cast<decltype(all_one) &>(all_two);` to achieve. Should all members of `all_one` get `2` assigned? The title suggests that you want to use 2 different values for initialization

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` is definitely the right tool (for the wrong job), anything else assumes sanity in field definitions. There is no sanity here to assume, so you need to reinterpret the class bytes.

Comment: this might get you somewhere: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22560100/how-to-initialize-all-tuple-elements-by-the-same-arguments

Comment: Read up about layout compatible types and the prerequisites. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Standard_layout Couldn't you use arrays as alternative, and create member functions that return a reference to a certain element (to have a nice name)? Arrays are much easier to initialize.

Comment: I simplified my needs in the question body, in fact my work is a little more tricky. It is a big data table, but I have to use a struct because I need the named members to get the corresponding pointer to members.

Comment: Perhaps here you find some interesting ideas. Lots of different simple and sophisticated solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674635/member-pointer-to-array-element Especially the first three answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would argue that the first one is much more maintainable, with the right warnings enabled (and a modern compiler), you will see if your initializer list gets out of sync with the class fields at compile time.

As to your alternative.. you're using templates as compiler arguments, which is not what they're meant to be. That brings a whole slew of issues:

- instantiated templates get copied in memory, making your executable larger. Though in this case, I'm hoping your compiler is smart enough to see that the field structure is the same and treat it as one type.
- your code now works only with constant literal integers, no more run-time variables.
- there is indeed no guarantee that the memory structure of those two classes is the same. You can disable optimizations in most compilers (like pack, alignment, etc), but that comes at the cost of disabling optimizations, which isn't actually necessary except to support your specific code.

And related to the last one, if you ever need to consider whether this is ever going to break, you're heading down a very dark road. I mean any sane person can tell you it will "probably work", but the fact that you have no guarantees in the language that pretty much popularized memory corruption and buffer overflows should terrify you. Write constructors.